# Google OpenID/federated login periodically fails

Tags: django, openid

I'm developing a Django app that uses python-openid. The app is running on my development server at home.

Similar to stackoverflow's login mechanism, I'd like users to login to my website using their Google credentials.

The code I've implemented to do this, works well for a couple weeks, and then stops working. I get stuck during the login process on the following Google page:  https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with this message: "The page you requested is invalid." It'll randomly start working again, but fails every few weeks or so.

Going through Yahoo's login worked for months, and today has stopped working with the following message: "This page has expired, go back to the original page and please try again" on this page: https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth

Here is the request, as captured by LiveHttpHeaders for Google:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud

POST /accounts/o8/ud HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042513 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/3.0.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/
Content-Length:907
openid.ax.if_available=ext1&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.realm=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/&openid.return_to=http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/finish/?janrain_nonce=2009-10-05T19%3A10%3A11ZtioiRm&openid.ax.count.ext1=unlimited&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.sreg.optional=email&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.ns.sreg=http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1&openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUcnzec0bpeZRztjqPrr5TQUA0aPL7SIuOPOMgWxex2HRAP09AyJ&openid.ax.required=ext0&openid.ax.type.ext0=http://schema.openid.net/namePerson&openid.ax.type.ext1=http://schema.openid.net/contact/web/default

HTTP/1.x 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, and would love some help.

Comment: Does it fail once?  Over and over for a day or so?  What are the circumstances with which it starts working again?

Comment: I have a problem like yours. but some how much worse! I have no problem with logging the user in, but every other day, the identity string provided by google and should be unique changes! so users can't login with their accounts in my site anymore. I don't know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you are using is generating a bad URL request. The real URL is https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id, so try to fix the "ud" at the end changing it by an "id".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can construct the uri and redirect the user to the uri with GET method. If you doing POST google expects some headers which I think it was not mentioned docs. Check the [sample](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#samples) request. I tried with GET without python-openid it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the `redirect_uri` and the `state` inside to see if they match. I remember having the issue of having mismatched `state` sometimes ago with Google Login.

Btw if you use Django, I would recommend using [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) which is currently active and supports multiple social login options (if at some point you consider adding more social login providers).